# Stream from PS3 to Android?

Tags: video-streaming

I am able to stream content from my Android device to the PS3 and watch it on the TV that's connected to the PS3.

What I want to do is stream the game play video from PS3 to my android device.

I have an Android stick I connect to my other TV and the stick allows to receive streams.

Any ideas?